# How do I set Excel formulas with Win32::OLE?

Tags: perl, excel, excel-formula, win32ole

Can anybody tell me, why the `...->{FormulaR1C1} = '=SUMME( "R[-3]C:R[-1]C" )';` doesn't work. In the Cell where the result should appear I get "#Wert!" ( maybe "Value" in English ). With the WENN(IF)-formula I get what I expect.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use warnings;
use strict;
use Win32::OLE qw;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;
my $xl = Win32::OLE::Const -> Load( 'Microsoft Excel' );
my $excelfile = 'win32_ole_excel.xls';
my $excel = Win32::OLE -> GetActiveObject( 'Excel.Application' ) || Win32::OLE -> new( 'Excel.Application', 'Quit' ) or die $!;

my $workbook = $excel -> Workbooks -> Add();
my $sheet = $workbook -> Worksheets( 1 );
$sheet -> Activate;


$sheet->Range( 'A3' )->{Value} = 10;
$sheet->Range( 'B3' )->{FormulaR1C1} = '=WENN( "RC[-1]" > 5; "OK"; "Not OK")'; # IF(,,); workes fine


$sheet->Range( 'G1' )->{Value} = 3;
$sheet->Range( 'G2' )->{Value} = 7;
$sheet->Range( 'G3' )->{Value} = 6;
$sheet->Range( 'G4' )->{FormulaR1C1} = '=SUMME( "R[-3]C:R[-1]C" )'; # SUM(); doesn't work


$workbook -> SaveAs( { Filename => $excelfile, FileFormat => xlWorkbookNormal } );
```

Comment: @sid_com - I added my version of the code which works for me. Have you had a look to see if it works for you? (you'll need at least to convert IF/WENN, SUMME/SUM and also the IF to use semicolons)

Comment: I can't test with a English version. But with my version it doesn't work.With "$sheet->Range( 'B3' )->{Value} = '=WENN( A3 > 5; "OK"; "Not OK")';" and "$sheet->Range( 'G4' )->{Value} = '=SUMME(G1;G3)';" it works fine ( I have to use quote around OK and Not OK ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the [perl-community.de](http://www.perl-community.de/bat/poard/start) I have now a solution:
I have to set

```
$excel->{ReferenceStyle} = $xl->{xlR1C1};
```

and use `Z1S1` instead of `R1C1`

```
=SUMME(Z(-2)S:Z(-1)S)
```

But it looks like that in the German version I have to choose between the `A1` and the `Z1S1` (`R1C1`) notation.

Comment: Sounds like this was your problem all along - strange. If this is your accepted solution, you should mark this as the answer of the question to close it. It'll help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need quotes around the SUM range. It should be explicit:

```
=SUMME(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)
```

Additional point - your IF/WENN formula is incorrect. It is trying to compare the string "RC[-1]" to the number 5 and coming up with YES! THE STRING IS GREATER. It is not doing what you think it is doing... you should take out the quotes around the references here as well.

**EDIT:** Here's my version of you code, which runs without any errors. Changes are commented. Had to apply a few changes for the English version of Excel. Ran against *ActivePerl 5.10.1 Build 1006*.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use warnings;
use strict;
# CHANGE - empty qw caused compilation error
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;
my $xl = Win32::OLE::Const -> Load( 'Microsoft Excel' );
# CHANGE - set path
my $excelfile = 'C:\win32_ole_excel.xls';
my $excel = Win32::OLE -> GetActiveObject( 'Excel.Application' ) || Win32::OLE -> new( 'Excel.Application', 'Quit' ) or die $!;

my $workbook = $excel -> Workbooks -> Add();
my $sheet = $workbook -> Worksheets( 1 );
$sheet -> Activate;

$sheet->Range( 'A3' )->{Value} = 10;
# CHANGE - Use IF, use commas, took quotes out around range
$sheet->Range( 'B3' )->{FormulaR1C1} = '=IF( RC[-1] > 5, OK, Not OK)'; # IF(,,); workes fine

$sheet->Range( 'G1' )->{Value} = 3;
$sheet->Range( 'G2' )->{Value} = 7;
$sheet->Range( 'G3' )->{Value} = 6;
# CHANGE - Use SUM, took quotes out around range
$sheet->Range( 'G4' )->{FormulaR1C1} = '=SUM(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)'; # SUM(); doesn't work

$workbook -> SaveAs( { Filename => $excelfile, FileFormat => xlWorkbookNormal } );
```

Comment: Without the quotes I get an errormessage:
Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80020009: "Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten"
    in PROPERTYPUT "FormulaR1C1" at C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\pp\Eigene Date
ien\excel.pl line 113

Comment: Just to check, you now have... $sheet->Range( 'G4' )->{FormulaR1C1} = '=SUMME(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)';

Comment: @ Joel : Yes.
Update: considering Joel's commend, neither of the two formula works.